# In ASP.net, is there a way to give a value to a validator in your .ascx file from the related .ascx.cs file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, ascx, customvalidator

I'm trying to get a web page to show an error without resetting itself, currently I'm doing this through a try catch block, is there any way to have the C# give a true or false value to an asp:CustomValidator control?

Comment: Your company is still using ASP.NET WebForms?

Comment: Tragically, this whole code base has been around since 2007.

Comment: https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2011/12/06/integrating-ajax-code-into-asp-net-validation-infrastructure.aspx?m=1

Comment: I guess the problem comes from the value not being stored in the UI, I would have written a javascript validation function if I could have, the value is a boolean that the c# is getting from our database.